# How to add a string method?

Tags: python

I'm doing an online course to get better at python, one of the questions isn't passing I don't know if it's the code or the sites interpreter is wrong.

I've been given the following instructions

> Add a `__str__` method to GameScore that returns the score in the string
>   "Player 1: 5; Player 2: 10", using the correct values from self.score.
>   self.score is a tuple with Player 1's score and Player 2's score like
>   (5, 10). You do not need to define self.score. It comes from the Game class.

This is my code

```
from game import Game

class GameScore(Game):
   def __Str__(self):
       return "Player 1: %s Player 2: %s" %(self.score[0], self.score[1])
```

I get this error

```
 Expected "Player 1: 5; Player 2: 2". Got "<__main__.GameScore object at 0x7f56c2a04b38>".
```

Comment: Lower case `__str__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is capitalization: you need `__str__` but named your method `__Str__`.

Comment: Thankyou that was it, it worked but it isn't passing though I just get a message. 'Expected "Player 1: 5; Player 2: 2". Got "Player 1: 5 Player 2: 2".'

Comment: Stare real hard at the strings. I see a semicolon.